# Is there any way of deploying Heroku PostgreSQL configuration to a new app via a git repo?

Tags: postgresql, git, heroku, configuration, heroku-postgres

We are making a series of apps, whose backends and frontends are forked from a common git codebase, and which share a database schema, but have different data within each.

At the moment we are running PostgreSQL database setup manually, but would like to be able to track these commands via git, and ideally, be able to provision databases in new Heroku apps in an automated way.

Is this possible? If not, are there any patterns for this that are effective?

*Note: we don't want to actually backup the data itself, just the process of creating the tables, data schema, etc.